# AutoMapper Dependency Injection with ITypeConverter

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper, typeconverter

I'm trying to use Automapper to convert all my DateTimes from UTC to Local Time but i need to inject an interface into ITypeConverter... I'm receiving this error when I run the application: **MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**

I think that the problem is with the dependency injection code!

Anyone can help me?

**UserRepository:**

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private static readonly MapperConfiguration Config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<User, User>();

        cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing<UtcToLocalConverter>();
    });

    public List<User> GetById(string[] ids)
    {
        var result = BuildQuery().Where(w => ids.Contains(w.UserName)).ToList();

        var mapper = Config.CreateMapper();

        return mapper.Map<List<User>>(result); // Throws error !!!
    }

    #region Helper

    private IQueryable<User> BuildQuery()
    {
        return Settings.EpedDb.User;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class UtcToLocalConverter : ITypeConverter<DateTime?, DateTime?>
{
    public UtcToLocalConverter(IBaseSettings baseClass) // I tried to inject here!!!
    {
        Settings = baseClass;
    }

    private IBaseSettings Settings { get; }

    public DateTime? Convert(DateTime? source, DateTime? destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source == null) return null;

        var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Settings.UserData.TimeZone);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)source, DateTimeKind.Utc), tzi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as a screenshot image. Can you copy and paste the relevant code into your question?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Thanks for the suggestion! What do you think about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hunch is correct: you can't inject any parameters into the constructor when you use `CreateUsing<TTypeConverter>()`. The type must have a parameterless constructor.

You could pass a single instance to `CreateUsing()`:

```
var converter = new UtcToLocalConverter(mySettings);
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing(converter);
```

But I suspect that won't work because you're using dependency injection to try to handle the user's time zone at runtime.

I think the **real** solution to your problem is to not deal with time zones at this layer of your application. The .NET `DateTime` class is notoriously bad at handling time zones.

You should:

- Use `DateTimeOffset?` instead of `DateTime?`
- Always store dates in UTC (offset 0)
- Don't worry about converting time zones in your application code
- At the rendering or presentation layer, render the UTC date in the user's local time zone

This is a much cleaner way of handling dates and time zones.

Answer (score 2):

What @NateBarbettini said makes sense, but this can be done using `ConstructServicesUsing`. The docs are [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html).